# Lifecycle of an application when it receives update from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Could anybody explain or share links to the documentation describing what happens with an application when it receives updates from Google Play? Especially I'm interested in these questions:

1. When an app receives an update, does it get recreated (i.e. gets stopped and launched again).

   - If it does, will it be a cold start or a warm one after updating?
2. What happens with JobScheduler jobs? I know that pressing the "Force stop" button in the settings of an application forces all existing jobs to be stopped. Will an app update do the same?
3. Are there any tools for testing app updates? I know that some people recommend using `adb -r install`. Will this installation be close to what happens during real update?

Answer (score 1):

1. It will be cold start
2. The JobScheduler jobs will stop run as well, since [they are part of the application process](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler), and the application process is killed
3. ADB -r will just re-install the same APK, as you can see in [ADB source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/ec54ef7a8d762ca35f6b4a63925ab2e72ce85d13/adb/client/adb_install.cpp#L320), that means the package signature will be verified (happens also in the Playstore). However, any additional features, such as [APK split](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) are not supported.